# Unity C# - Multiple Prefabs with the same script causing issues running a function on another object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

sorry if it's not ideal to post Unity questions here.
I am creating one of those fake mobile games where  you have to go through the right gate just to see how easy they are to make [image: screenshot of the game]

On the gates will be maths problems and your score will be the answer.
I have changed the gates to be the answer for now to help with debugging.

The problem is, even though everything looks as though it's right, the gates are showing the correct values, when I run my players AddScore function it does not update properly.
The gates are spawned every 3 seconds, I have debuggd it enough to know for sure it is adding of the most recent gate that has been spanwed, rather than the one the player is going through

Is there any way my code can be changed to prevent this?

Thank you in advance

```
//Relevant player code
public static int score;

void Start()
{
    score = 0;
}

public void AddScore(int scoretoadd)
{
    score += scoretoadd;
    Debug.Log(score);
}
```

.

```
// The script on each gate prefab
public class GateScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI txt;
    private int qIndex;
    public static int points;
    //A dictionary of questions and their respective answers
    Dictionary<string, int> questions = new Dictionary<string, int>() { 
        {"4 x 3", 12},
        {"8 x 8", 64},
        {"4 x 4", 16},
        {"3 x 9", 27},
        {"9 x 7", 63}

    };  
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //Get a random number and use that to pull a random index from the dictionary
        qIndex = Random.Range(0, questions.Count);
        KeyValuePair<string, int> pair = questions.ElementAt(qIndex);
        //Sets points for this gate to the value in the dictionary
        points = pair.Value;
        //Changes the text on the gate
        txt.text = pair.Value.ToString();
        //Debug.Log(pair.Value + " " + pair.Key);

    }

    //Function to add score to player
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            collision.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerController>().AddScore(points);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want different point values on gates. But you have a static single value.  There lies your issue

Comment: Ah I think it is fixed! It was because points was static which meant that was getting overwritten each time a new gate spawned.

Comment: Thanks BugFinder, that's exactly what was wrong

Answer (score 0):

The score variable was static causing it to be overwritten by the newest gate that was spawning